# Не удается отправить данные, если соединение отсутствует в состоянии «Подключено»

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

Пытаюсь понять работу хабов в SignalR. После нажатия на кнопку "осправить" в чате сообшение не появляеться. Зато появляется ощибка

```
    signalr-client-1.0.0-alpha2-final.min.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State
    at c.HttpConnection.send (signalr-client-1.0.0-alpha2-final.min.js:1)
    at Promise (signalr-client-1.0.0-alpha2-final`.`min.js:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at c.HubConnection.invoke (signalr-client-1.0.0-alpha2-final.min.js:1)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> ((index):95)
```

**Startup class**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSignalR();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //SignalR
        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("chat");
        });

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

**packege.json**

```
    {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@aspnet/signalr-client": "^1.0.0-alpha2-final"
  }
}
```

**chathub class**

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task Send(string message, string userName)
    {
        await Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Send", message, userName);
    }
}
```

**index.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>SignalR Chat</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="loginBlock">
        Введите логин:<br />
        <input id="userName" type="text" />
        <input id="loginBtn" type="button" value="Войти" />
    </div><br />

    <div id="header"></div><br />

    <div id="inputForm">
        <input type="text" id="message" />
        <input type="button" id="sendBtn" value="Отправить" />
    </div>
    <div id="chatroom"></div>
    <script src="js/signalr-client-1.0.0-alpha2-final.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let hubUrl = 'http://localhost:53759/chat';
        let httpConnection = new signalR.HttpConnection(hubUrl);
        let hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnection(httpConnection);
        let userName = '';
        // получение сообщения от сервера
        hubConnection.on('Send', function (message, userName) {

            // создаем элемент <b> для имени пользователя
            let userNameElem = document.createElement("b");
            userNameElem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(userName + ': '));

            // создает элемент <p> для сообщения пользователя
            let elem = document.createElement("p");
            elem.appendChild(userNameElem);
            elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));

            var firstElem = document.getElementById("chatroom").firstChild;
            document.getElementById("chatroom").insertBefore(elem, firstElem);

        });

        // установка имени пользователя
        document.getElementById("loginBtn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            userName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
            document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = '<h3>Welcome ' + userName + '</h3>';
        });
        // отправка сообщения на сервер
        document.getElementById("sendBtn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            let message = document.getElementById("message").value;
            hubConnection.invoke('Send', message, userName);
        });

        hubConnection.start();
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```